# Setting rows as a Set Data source

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatables, combobox, excel-2016

Hey guys so I can't embed an image so I will do the best I can at explaining...

I'm in excel creating a Daily foods organization chart. I have two Tables.
Table 1 has all possible foods to pick from and their average macronutrients. Table 2 has columns for the food that I did eat, plus an extra column for the specific amount of that food serving I ate.

Im trying to make it so that in table two when I enter a food from the list it takes that foods information and multiplies it by the amount of servings I ate. The big problem is I don't know how to extract all the data from a row in the food list and have it all be placed into the second table without scrolling all the way down the list to find the food, copying the data and then manually multiplying all its values by the serving size I ate, it's just way to tedious. I need to find a way to streamline the process...

I thought I could try a combo-box to query a specific foods data quickly and then if I can get it to pull up all data specific to that food then just insert a serving size to multiply all macros by. Though this has been unsuccessful as I can't seem to get combo-box to query data in Excel 2019 16.43 as  there doesnt seem to be a properties box for it like in the older versions.

Any Ideas as to how this could be done? Thanks

Comment: Consider using VLOOKUP(). Give each food in your list a unique number or short ID, like #12 or "BRC" for *Broccoli*. Then, in your consumption table you enter "20 [grams] or BRC" and VLOOKUP finds both the term "Broccoli" and the nutritional value per gram, multiplies that with 20 and displays the result.

Comment: Ah okay so that sort of works but along with querying the foods name I need it to also grab the foods macro values and place them in the 2nd table to be multiplied by the serving size also... so essentially I need to query multiple values with one Vlookup. I would use power query but is it not available for macs on 2019 Excel? I can't find it.

Comment: If you want two values from two cells you need to construct two VLOOKUPs. If you want to concatenate the two results in one cell you would still use two VLOOKUPs and concatenate the returns.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I would like to output 5 values when inputting one Vlookup request. For example... If I look up the ID# 67 for a Vlookup food, I would like to output the Protein, lipids, carbs, sugars fiber values for that food in 5 seperate cells all labeled for those specific macros. I'd like to get all the foods info using only one Vlookup, and the only instance I can see of this working would be using Power Query? (which I can't use since I have a mac)

Comment: If you can give more info on what the FOOD column in both your tables are called you can use INDEX([food],MATCH([get match in proper row]), MATCH([get match of description in table header]))

Comment: Well so what I've been trying to do is use find a way to make a formula that can Index the food ID# column in Table 1 (which contains all the foods info Horizontally) and once I index that ID # then scan across the rows of that food and output all its info into the 2nd table to be multiplied by serving size... This is what Iv'e been using but still getting error --> =INDEX(A18:C24, SMALL(IF(C28=A18:A24, ROW(A18:A24)-MIN(ROW(A18:A24))+1, ""), ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1))